# MySQL, How to pass @var after ADD keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

First I create my table with one text column in 5.6.34 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) like so :

```
CREATE TABLE `$_query_test`.`t1` ( c1 TEXT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Then I execute:

```
SET @var = 321; INSERT INTO `t1` (c1) VALUES (@var);
```

I get one entry with a value of `321` as expected, but when i execute:

```
SET @var = '_string_';
ALTER TABLE `t1` ADD @var TEXT;
```

I get an error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@var TEXT' at line 1

What is the proper syntax to do something like this? I have searched far and wide and so far got nothing on this.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL if you want to replace table names, column names, database names, function names, and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot substitute an sql variable in place of an identifier (e.g. field name, table name, etc). Period.

What you can do is to create the full sql statement as a string either on application level or in mysql with the identifier already substituted and you execute the full statement.

In mysql you can do this via [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `t1` ADD ', @var, ' TEXT');
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: I have tested your query and got an error as well. But also I successfully executed this one: 
`PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse';
SET @a = 3;
SET @b = 4;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;`

However I couldn't construct a query for my alter table case.

Comment: Well, you need to debug your query. Since you have not shared any specifics eith us, I cannot help you further.

Comment: I debugged it just now and the answer is:

``SET @var = 'new_column_prefix';
SET @s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `t1` ADD ', @var,' TEXT;');
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt3;``

Thanks a lot. Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables for values but not field names. You will need to do that with whatever server language you are using before composing the alter table.